# Is there a way to apply the rule to a specific assumption in Isabelle?

Tags: verification, isabelle, formal-verification

Here is my goal

```
...
∀a b. P1 a b  ⟹ 
∀a b. P2 a b  ⟹
...
⟹ some goal
```

I want to apply the lemma to the second assumption

```
lemma K: ⟦ ∀a b. P a b⟧ ⟹ ∀b. P a b"
```

by using

```
apply (drule_tac a = "x" in K)
```

but Isabelle always firstly applies the tactic to the first assumption, how can I only apply the tactic to the second assumption?

Actually, my goal is

```
...
∀b. Γ b ≠ Γ' b ⟶
           b ∉ set (llocked C1) ∧ (Γ b, Γ' b) ∈ RGUnion R G2 b ∧ disjoint (dom h1) (dom (Γ' b)) ⟶
           rgsep_safe n C1 s h1 Γ' (RGUnion R G2) G1 Q1 ⟹
       ∀b. Γ b ≠ Γ' b ⟶
           b ∉ set (llocked C2) ∧ (Γ b, Γ' b) ∈ RGUnion R G1 b ∧ disjoint (dom h2) (dom (Γ' b)) ⟶
           rgsep_safe n C2 s h2 Γ' (RGUnion R G1) G2 Q2 ⟹
       rgsep_safe n C2 s h2 Γ' (RGUnion R G1) G2 Q2
```

and I want to use the lemma on the second assumtion

```
theorem K1: ∀b. ?P b ⟶ ?Q ⟹ ∀b. ?P b ⟹ ?Q
```

to make the goal become

```
...
∀b. Γ b ≠ Γ' b ⟶
           b ∉ set (llocked C1) ∧ (Γ b, Γ' b) ∈ RGUnion R G2 b ∧ disjoint (dom h1) (dom (Γ' b)) ⟶
           rgsep_safe n C1 s h1 Γ' (RGUnion R G2) G1 Q1 ⟹
∀b. Γ b ≠ Γ' b ⟶
           b ∉ set (llocked C2) ∧ (Γ b, Γ' b) ∈ RGUnion R G1 b ∧ disjoint (dom h2) (dom (Γ' b))
```

Comment: I have found a solution that if you found your rule applied on wrong assumption, you can  use back to switch the assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ugly hacks that can allow you to bypass the first assumption (e.g. by deleting it or reordering them). Already drule_tac is heading in that direction. Better by far is to use a structured proof, if it's practical for your problem. Then it's easy to name your assumptions and join them to "K" using the OF attribute.

Your theorem `K1` is useless: it doesn't do what you think it does because of how the scope of quantifiers works. I tried an experiment with a simpler version of your goal and made quite a bit of progress by typing

apply (simp flip: imp_conjL)

This admittedly obscure step converts your implications into conjunctions; the simplifier notices that the quantified variable doesn't appear on the right-hand side, so all you need to do now is exhibit a `b` satisfying the three conditions

1. Γ b ≠ Γ' b
2. b ∉ set (llocked C2)
3. (Γ b, Γ' b) ∈ RGUnion R G1 b ∧ disjoint (dom h2) (dom (Γ' b))

You will get a much nicer looking proof if you prove these facts first. If they are available then you may find that the automation proves the goal you wanted automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have detailed my goal. So how can I solve this problem?